# Java Swing jComboBox not filling from Database

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, jdbc

So I am working on a task force schedule for my mothers charity project. The aim is to check in the volunteers, display the roster for times and what station they are at. I have successfully built a login form, that pulls the data from the database and verify if your entered username (from dropdown) and password are correct. I have this method (NB: for the login form, it works and is not the problem) to fill the username dropdown called `'cbxUsername'` which is called inside the main method when the window loads:

```
public void loginToProgram() throws Exception{
        user = (String) cbxUsername.getSelectedItem();
        if(user == "Please select a username"){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, You need to select a username to continue");
        }else if(txtPassword.getText().length() == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, You need to enter a password to continue");
        } else {
            checkAuth();
        }

}
```

and then this method is refered to above, this is the checkAuth() method:

```
public void checkAuth() throws Exception{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/crm", "root", "t00rt00r");
    PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE `username` = '"+ user +"'");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    if(result.next() != false){
        pass = result.getString(1);
    }
    if(txtPassword.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(pass)){
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Worked");
        CheckIn chk =  new CheckIn();

        chk.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, wrong password");
    }
}
```

Now I have copied the first code (the method 'loginToProgram()') and altered it abit.

Now I have a new window called 'CheckIn', with a jComboBox called 'cbxCIFirstName'. The code to fill up this combobox is:

```
public static void fillFirstNameCombobox() throws Exception{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/crm", "root", "t00rt00r");
    PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT `first_name` FROM `volunteers`");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    cbxCIFirstName.setToolTipText("Select a first name");
    cbxCIFirstName.setEditable(true);
    cbxCIFirstName.addItem("Please Select a first name");
    while(result.next()){
        cbxCILastName.addItem(result.getString(1));
    }
    System.out.println(result.getString(1));
}
```

Please note: I put the `System.out.println(result.getString(1));` there just to see if it was coming through in the console, and it is NOT coming through on the console. What am I doing wrong? Here is my Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                fillFirstNameCombobox();
                CheckIn frame = new CheckIn();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, any comments, guides, tutorials or anything I will take into consideration and try!

Thanks for your time, reading this post and thanks in advance for your answers,
Josh.

Comment: `user == "Please select a username"` : Use `equals` for checking `String` equality.

Comment: You only use one equals ie, '=', when assigning a value

Comment: user="string" and userB="string", there you will receive false for user==userB but true for user.equals(userB), however if you had userB=user then user==userB will be true because it is the same object.

Comment: You are calling System.out.println(result.getString(1)); just when the loop finishes, when the ResultSet state has no next element, try adding that print inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void fillFirstNameCombobox() throws Exception{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/crm", "root", "t00rt00r");
    PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT `first_name` FROM `volunteers`");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    cbxCIFirstName.setToolTipText("Select a first name");
    cbxCIFirstName.setEditable(true);
    cbxCIFirstName.addItem("Please Select a first name");
    while(result.next()){
        cbxCILastName.addItem(result.getString(1)); 
    }
    System.out.println(result.getString(1));// this line can not be outside while loop
}
```

make this way

```
  public static void fillFirstNameCombobox() throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/crm", "root", "t00rt00r");
        PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT first_name FROM volunteers");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        cbxCIFirstName.setToolTipText("Select a first name");
        cbxCIFirstName.setEditable(true);
        cbxCIFirstName.addItem("Please Select a first name");
        while(result.next()){
            cbxCILastName.addItem(result.getString(1)); 
System.out.println(result.getString(1));// this line can not be outside while loop
        }

}
```

**REASON**

Actually the cursor is at top level.When you are calling result.next) then the cursor comes down and at the end the cursor lies at bottom.
That means at the end it return false and control comes out of while.
You are trying to print after the `while`  that means the cursor is already at the bottom so thats the problem.

Also the way you are using preparedstatement is not the right way.
use this way

```
PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE `username` = ?);
statement.setString(1,user );
```

Comment: I tried that, I originally didn't even have the print out statement, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Josh did you try my way?if yes are you getting any error if yes post the error else post the output

Comment: yes I copied your code exact and it gave me the exact same thing as when I did it, nothing. I have not encountered any errors. Thanks

Comment: @Josh try with this way and let me know SELECT * FROM volunteers.Just edit your code and replace with this line.If your table is not empty then you will definitely output

Comment: I took a break, I tried the preparedstatement like you said, seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: And the other thing I did, instead of calling the fillFirstNameCombobox() method in the main sub, I called it in the class's constructor

Comment: Without a closing quote, `statement` won't compile. Why cast `Connection` and `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: eclipse did it automatically

Answer (score 0):

For all who are reading this thread, I fixed it by using the right preparedStatement method as given by @javaBeginner (thanks) and then instead of calling the method "fillFirstNameCombobox()" from the main method, I called it from the class's constructor, so the class is called "ClockIn", I called it on the last line of the constructor/method "ClockIn()"